# Display json python discord bot

Tags: python, json, bots, display, discord.py

I have a json file json that stores the xp and level of people on my server.
I was doing a leaderboard to show the people who have the most xp on the server, but it is not working, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide a string to send_message. If you want to have the people who have the most xp show up in order, and say five of them, you'd probably want to do something like

```
leaderboard = sorted(users, key=lambda x:users [x]["xp"])[5:]
await Bot.send_message(message.channel, "\n".join(leaderboard))
```

Comment: add `reverse=True` to the sorted to get the highest 10 instead of the lowest 10. `sorted(users, key=..., reverse=True)`. To get the name, you probably want to get the usernames seperately, iterator or listcomp is your best bet.